# Using matrix exponential to solve linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, linear-solver, linear-system

Consider the system of linear equations:

$$
Ax=b
\tag{1}
\label{eq1}
$$

where

- $A\in\mathbb F^{n\times n}$, diagonalizable dense matrix, over the field $\mathbb F$ of real or complex numbers,
- $x\in \mathbb F^{n\times 1}$ is a vector of unknowns
- $b\in \mathbb F^{n\times 1}$ is a known right-hand side vector
- $n$ is in the order of 1000–10000

Unlike the usual system of linear equations, I do not have access to $A$ itself; however, I have access to the matrix exponential $e^A$. The matrix exponential is accessible both as an explicit matrix and, consequently, as a function acting on a vector.

What are my options for finding the solution of $\eqref{eq1}$ knowing only the matrix exponential? Computing [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) does not seem the best option as I doubt being able to get anything numerically stable and reasonably efficient.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: 1. Have you tried some ready-to-use methods for the matrix logarithm such as Matlab's `logm(E) \ b`, before writing it off as unstable / inefficient? 2. Are $A$ and $E=\exp(A)$ sparse or dense?

Comment: Is $B=e^A$ close to unity? Then you can use Taylor expansion $A = log(B) = (B-I) + (B-I)^2/2 - (B-I)^3/3 + ...$

Comment: @FedericoPoloni $A$ and $E$ are dense. I would have to export the matrix to Matlab and try it there, which I should do. That is a "bruteforce" method in my initial assessment – and I certainly have to try it at least on a couple of examples.

Comment: @MaximUmansky nope, $e^A$ is not close to unity.

Comment: (What is $\|A\|$, just to have an idea?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are effectively asking how to compute $y=(\log M )^{-1}b$, where $M=e^A$ is the given matrix. There are several methods for computing $f(M)b$ without forming $f(M)$, and they are reviewed [here](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/narep/narep436.pdf). One general method is to use Cauchy’s theorem,
$$y=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma f(z)(zI - M)^{-1}b\,dz,$$
with $f(x) = 1/\log(x)$. $\Gamma$ is a contour that encloses all the eigenvalues of $M$, so you need to first estimate the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue, say, with a power method. Then you approximate the integral with the trapezoidal rule. You need to solve several shifted systems of the form $(zI-M)x =b$, for which a preliminary reduction to Hessenberg form is useful.

Comment: great reference. It seems like exactly what I hoped for. I will have to analyze it against computing $\log M$, but now I have an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am expanding my comment into an answer. I don't think that the method is efficient, but I think that it can be used to obtain the matrix $A$ from $e^{A}$.

We know that

$$\frac{d e^{tA}}{dt} = e^{tA} A\, ,$$

so, we could use

$$\left.\frac{d e^{tA}}{dt}\right|_{t=0} = A\, ,$$

if we can approximate the derivative

$$\frac{d e^{tA}}{dt} \approx D(A)\, .$$

For example, we could use a forward finite difference

$$\left.\frac{d e^{tA}}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \approx \frac{e^{hA} - I}{h}\, ,$$

but the problem is that we need to compute the fractional power of the matrix $e^{A}$. Maybe we could take advantage of higher-order approximations and just use integer powers of the matrix, but a couple I tried didn't work properly.

It seems to work, but I doubt it is efficient.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import logm, fractional_matrix_power as powm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eA = np.array([
    [1, -1],
    [1, 2]])
A = logm(eA)
rel_error = []
steps = [1, 1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5]
for h in steps:
    A1 = np.real((powm(eA, h) - np.eye(2))/h)
    rel_error.append(np.linalg.norm(A - A1)/np.linalg.norm(A))

plt.loglog(steps, rel_error)
plt.xlabel("Relative error")
plt.xlabel("$h$")
plt.savefig("matexp.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you used a pretty bad example to test your method here. Based on OP's question, his matrix is in the order of $1000 \times 1000$ to $10000 \times 10000$, and I believe your method won't converge at all for a $1000 \times 1000$ matrix. Replace your $2 \times 2$ matrix by this `n = 1000 eA = np.random.rand(n,n)` and you would see by decreasing $h$ you won't get a convergence.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, I tested it with the example provided by Federico Poloni.

Comment: I guess your finite-difference expression can be also interpreted as a consequence of the property (or definition) of the exponential function, $exp(x) = lim(1+x/n)^n$ for large n, or $x = lim (n(e^{x/n}-1))$. If we had a good way to find the $n^{th}$ root of our given matrix $e^A$ then this would be indeed a possible way to approximate matrix A.

Comment: Here is a good survey of calculation methods for finding a nth root of a matrix, https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/bini_higham_pth_root_na_2005.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

If we diagonalize matrix $A$ by finding the transformation S such that $A = S D S^{-1}$ where D is a diagonal matrix and the diagonal elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ then the same transformation makes $e^A$ diagonal, and the eigenvalues are $e^{\lambda_k}$. So diagonalizing $e^A$ and taking log of eigenvalues we find matrix $D$, which is sufficient to solve the linear system; and using the transformation $S$ we can find the original matrix $A.$

Alternatively, if $B=e^A$ is close enough to unity, you can use Taylor expansion to find $A$, $A = log(B) = (B-I) + (B-I)^2/2 - (B-I)^3/3 + ...$

Comment: I think that's just how matrix logarithms work

Comment: That’s how matrix logarithm’s work in exact arithmetic and for normal matrices in floating point. For general diagonalizable matrices, $S$ mat be ill-conditioned so that significant errors may result from this approach.

Comment: You are slowly re-inventing the standard methods to compute logarithms of dense matrices. :) The next step is using the identity $\log(A) = 2^s \log(A^{1/2^s})$ to get a matrix closer to the identity, and replace Taylor with Padé which has a better convergence radius.

Comment: @Federico Poloni How about other expansions for $ln(x)$, in particular the second one in http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm? I guess it can be applied for matrices too, if we first calculate the inverse of our given $e^A$; and convergence of this series is not restricted to norm $|| e^A-I || $ < 1.

Comment: It's possible that it could be made to work, but I have no direct experience. Convergence of that series is restricted to matrices with no eigenvalues $\lambda < 1/2$, if I understand correctly (not clear how this generalizes to complex numbers). The problem is, it is easy to ensure that a matrix has no *large* eigenvalues (small norm implies that), but it is more difficult to ensure that it has no *small* eigenvalues).